# RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateParsingException: Exception occurs while decoding string value in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, razor-2

**Exception Details:**

```
{"A space or line break was encountered after the \"@\" character.  Only valid identifiers, keywords, comments, \"(\" and \"{\" are valid at the start of a code block and they must occur immediately following \"@\" with no space in between."}
```

Hi in my mvc3 project, i have got an exception while i'm decoding the string value using

```
   string s="(500500) Features: â€¢ 170 GPH @ 1 ft â€¢ Operates submersed.";
   string DecodedValue = Server.HtmlDecode(Razor.Parse(s));
```

[image]

Here it doesn't encoding and exception was caught. How i got the decoded value.

Comment: I guess you need to escpace the `@` with `@@` so your string should be `"(500500) Features: â€¢ 170 GPH @@ 1 ft â€¢ Operates submersed."`

Comment: @nemesv i will check it and tell..

Comment: Hai @nemesv It works well.. thanks a lot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to parse the following string as a Razor template:

```
"(500500) Features: â€¢ 170 GPH @ 1 ft â€¢ Operates submersed."
```

In Razor, the `@` character denotes that the following expression should be parsed as C#. If you want it to appear as a literal string, you need to escape it:

```
"(500500) Features: â€¢ 170 GPH @@ 1 ft â€¢ Operates submersed."
```

However, it's not clear why this needs to be parsed as Razor at all, since you are not passing any variable data. Why can't you simply use the following?

```
string s="(500500) Features: â€¢ 170 GPH @ 1 ft â€¢ Operates submersed.";
string DecodedValue = Server.HtmlDecode(s);
```

Comment: Sometimes i have &lt;p&gt;
 This replacement is for all IQ 2020 controllers in all Hot Spring, Limelight, and Tiger River spas up to 2008&lt;br /&gt;
 Item Number:74618&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
 &amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
 &lt;span style=&quot;font-size: 18px;&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Click the Videos tab to see a installation video&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
 &amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;     to decode using Server.HtmlDecode(Razor.Parse(s)); thats why...?

Comment: Then you need to escape the `@` character. Or create independent cshtml template files.

Comment: Ya i will try it now @Ant P